# How can I back up my init file with Git?

Tags: init-file, git, backup

[The docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Location-of-init-file.html) say to keep the `.emacs` file in the `HOME` directory.

I'd like to share the file between multiple computers using a git repo. What is the best way to structure the repo without including everything else that's in `HOME`.

Do I have to turn `HOME` itself into a repo and include everything else in the directory in the .gitignore?

Comment: The docs you've linked to say "the init file may also be called `.emacs.d/init.el`. Many of the other files that are created by lisp packages are now stored in the `.emacs.d` directory too, so this keeps all your Emacs related files in one place", which essentially answers your question.

Comment: good point, I was reading that as "emacs may call the file"  instead of "you may call the file .emacs.d/init.el and emacs will run from that"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to to turn your whole home into a repo. `.emacs.d` will be enough, and cloning it whatever you go will do it too.

Supposing that your `.emacs.d` is a repo, to do that your `.gitignore` should look like:

```
/*
!init.el
!.gitignore
```

First line tells git to ignore everything, second line tells git that init.el shouldn't be ignored. Third line prevents git from ignoring the `.gitignore`. [More info here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Notice that if you ignore a subdirectory you won't be able to "unignore" files under it this way. Instead, use a `.gitignore` file specific to that subdirectory.

Comment: awesome, that was basically my plan except that I didn't know about `!`. Was going to commit just `.emacs.d/init.el` and then add ignore everything.

Comment: I can't imagine why you would want to include *only* your `init.el` file in your repository.  I would recommend that you use a 'normal' .gitignore approach of explicitly ignoring the things you don't want, and committing everything else.

Comment: @phils being in the need of including more things, or just split `init.el` into a set of manageable files, will inevitably happen sooner or later.